# UI-router: Scroll to top page on statechange in Internet explorer scrolls to top before next view loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-ui-router

In our angular application we want to scroll to the top of the page when a user navigates between pages. 
Unfortunately, not much was happening when we added the `autoscroll` attribute to our ui-view element. 
What did work however was listening to the `$stateChangeSuccess` event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (fromParams.pagNr !== toParams.pagNr) {
            $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that Internet Explorer scrolls to the top of the page *before* switching pages. 
I also tried `$viewContentLoaded`, but the page would scroll to the top for each child state loaded as well, which is undesired.

How can I implement this behavior cross-browser?